# Clipping raster image in ArcGIS problem column and row

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

Imagine I have x.tif (100x100 pixels) and Y.tif(10x10 pixels).

If I have to clip x.tif with the extent of Y.tif, the result of Z.tif should be 10x10 pixels. but the result of mine is 10x11 pixels.

The geographic coordinate, datum, and spatial references between x and y is the same. I've also checked the environment on clipping tools and check the "maintain clipping extent".

Is there anything I can do to clip the Z.tif with exact column and row?

Comment: Imagine you have two rasters whose corners match in the X dimension but are offset 50% of pixel size in the Y dimension. Any clip is going to bring one more row due to fragmentary overlap.

Comment: yeah, i've just see it. the pixel size is 500m. and there's overlap arround 200m difference between x and y image. is there any way to resolve this overlap?

Comment: You could Shift one or both rasters, which would generate accuracy/precision issues. You could downsample to 250m and shift only 50m. Or you could accept the 10x11 data, or construct your own clipping envelope. Lots of options.